# Converting program with C and asm code to a DLL

Tags: c#, c, dll, assembly

My algorithm contains C and asm code. I need to call this algorithm in a C# application. I was wondering if I could convert the C and asm code to a DLL and then call it in the C# console application. But I'm very unclear about how to convert the coupled C and asm code algorithm into a DLL. Any help is appreciated.

I know how to use PInvoke to call the DLL in C#. My issue is converting the combined C and asm code to a DLL. VS 2010 keeps vomitting errors when I try to use extern "C" and dllexport. There are over 90 errors!! Most of the errors are those complaining that C++ doesn't support the stuff I've used(though they are valid in C). Like for example, this line of code:

```
const u8 *error_string_base="ERROR: ";
```

gives an

> *error C4430: missing type specifier -int assumed. Note C++ does not support default-int*

Comment: Try and keep your question focused. If you know how to call a DLL from C#, then don't even mention it. And we can't help you fix errors if we don't know what they are.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call unmanaged code that is in a DLL from C#.

> Platform Invocation Services (PInvoke) allows managed code to call unmanaged functions that are implemented in a DLL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

You'll probably want to have a look at the topic *Calling a DLL Export Directly from C#*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx#pinvoke_callingdllexport

**UPDATE** (Based on your edit)

Compile your application in C mode rather than C++ mode

Go to properties -> c/c++ ->advanced -> compile as and select 'c'

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, I know how to use PInvoke to call the DLL in C#. My issue is converting the combined C and asm code to a DLL. VS 2010 keeps vomitting errors when I try to use extern "C" and dllexport. Any ideas?

Comment: @Shambavi, you'll need to include the errors and the lines that cause the errors for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: There are over 90 errors!! Most of the errors are those complaining that C++ doesn't support the stuff I've used(which are actually valid in C). Like for example, this line of code: const u8 *error_string_base="ERROR: "; gives an error C4430: missing type specifier -int assumed. Note C++ does not support default-int

Comment: Try compiling as C rather than C++ then... and do post specific error messages.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I am compiling it as C already. I'll get back to you with specific error messages.

Comment: What is u8? That's not a standard type. I recommend using stdtypes.h

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to Create a Dll Application(COM dll or Others) and Write your code in VC++
,which is very similar to C and you can also merge your asm code like this

```
 __asm {
         mov al, 2
         mov dx, 0xD007
         out dx, al
       }
```

,i mean using **__asm** keyword.Creating dll application is not a big deal ..There  is a lot of resources on net for this.Importing and Exporting Dll's have many constraint ,that's why your code  keeps vomitting errors .

Comment: Thanks a ton Alok! I'll try using VC++ and the __asm keyword. Should I use extern "C" for all the .h and .c files?